# What makes an equation integrable?

Tags: integration

I was working on my Discrete Mathematics and Probability Theory homework, and we were introduced to the $erf(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{z}e^{-x^2}dx$ function and were told it wasn't integrable. I remember back in high school my calculus teacher told me that they (the textbook makers and AP collegeboard) intentionally made the equations nice and easily integrable, and that there were lots of functions that are not integrable. So, what makes a function integrable analytically?

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: Integratable is not a word. Integrable is a word, although you might want to say "can be integrated using elementary methods", because it means something else in measure theory.

Comment: I think there are 2 definitions of integrable here.

1 is your "integratable" as you can determine the area under a given function using a certain type of integral. For example, I think Dirichlet function or something is not integratable using Riemann integratable but it is using Lebesgue integral, I think.

2 is integrable as in the integral over R of $|f| < \infty$. I guess integrable functions are integratable hahaha

Answer (score 0):

The $\operatorname{erf}$-function is integratable by the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Formal_definitions) of the integral. However there is none elementary expression for it.